# Web Game has many errors: does this matter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Recently I finished (or almost finished) coding a core concept of a web game that I'm still working on. However, when I run the code in Chrome (the game is meant for Webkit browsers only), I get a LOT of errors. But, they do not affect what the code is trying to achieve. The code is written in JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

To get into more detail, my code is part of a "Battle" sequence and is looped each turn. Each loop however produces hundreds of errors (I assume it can even produce 1000's each loop), with each successive loop producing more errors than the previous one. Depending on the number of turns the battle takes, the page may be spitting out thousands and thousands of errors each loop... not good. 
The errors are literally all "Cannot set property "className" of undefined" (my code uses a bunch of these to change the animations of some sprites I'm using). The good thing though, as mentioned above, is that these errors do not seem to be affecting the overall battle itself, ie the battle can progress smoothly.

So my question is this: Will the enormous amount of errors pose any kind of problem, for example to the browser or web page performance? I also plan to transfer this game onto Android and will be using WebView in Android Studio. Will the errors be any problem there either? Obviously I will try and fix this up, but if it isn't a big issue I will leave it for later and start working on other parts of the game.

Thank you for reading my question, and if it's confusing I will try to explain more.

Cheers.

Comment: There should be no errors. Nobody can help you more specifically if you don't post the code, the exact errors, etc. Errors reported in the console mean that your code is not really doing the things you think it is doing, because the errors terminate execution.

Comment: run inspect elements on stackoverflow and you will see a bunch of errors in the console.... errors happen......I assure you the best platforms in the world have errors or bugs.....However 1000 errors per loop, seems very excessive..

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your input. However I don't think anyone will want to read through at least 500 lines of code just to help with my problem. I'm just looking for a general answer. I will be tidying up the code and hopefully stopping all those errors later today. Cheers.

Comment: @user1639634 Yes, it is pretty excessive. As I mentioned above to Pointy I will be tidying up the page and hopefully ridding it of the errors later today. Thank you.

Comment: Good news guys, I fixed my code and now I am getting no errors! All I did was add an `if` statement that checks if the element exists on the page, and if it doesn't the code doesn't run which in turn doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news guys, I fixed my code and now I am getting no errors! All I did was add an `if` statement that checks if the element exists on the page, and if it doesn't the code doesn't run which in turn doesn't give an error.